# Tagging tests in mocha test suite

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

Is there a way to add tags to test cases so that I can run a particular test case instead of running the complete suite? If yes, can someone help me how to do it.

eg.

```
describe("User Service - create and search user", function() {
    var data;

    parseData('/Users/ksachdeva/node_modules/chakram/ns/tests/user-service/requestBodies/createUser.csv', execute);

        function execute(data) {

        before('should create a user', function () {

            res = call.post(testConfig.APP_URL + testConfig.CREATE_USER, JSON.parse(data));
            return expect(res).to.have.json(function(json)  {
            userid = json.user.userid;
           console.log("API Response ----> " + JSON.stringify(json));
           });

        });

        });
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The idea of Tagging in mocha is well described in [this WIKI page](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Tagging).

The main idea is to use particular keywords in your test (i.e. in the parent `describe` block) and then use a filter option (`grep`) to run only those tests.

Here's [the full list](https://mochajs.org/#usage) of mocha options.

From the CLI you can do:

```
$ mocha --grep <pattern>
```

Or

```
$ mocha -g <pattern>
```

Programmatically you can do:

```
// Instantiate a Mocha instance.
var mocha = new Mocha({
  grep: <String|RegExp>
});

mocha.addFile( 'test.js' );
mocha.run();
```